# Is there a way to plot corresponding points of two data frames?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with the same columns and date indices:

df1:

```
Date        T.TO AS.TO NTR.TO ... R.TO
2016-03-03  0.1  0.02  0.04       0.02
2016-03-04  0.09 0.01  0.02       0.02
2016-03-05  0.1  0.02  0.04       0.02
...
2019-03-03  0.09 0.01  0.02       0.02
```

df2:

```
Date        T.TO AS.TO NTR.TO ... R.TO
2016-03-03  0.01  0.32  0.04       0.02
2016-03-04  0.81  0.21  0.02       0.02
2016-03-05  0.01  0.12  0.04       0.02
...
2019-03-03  0.89  0.11  0.12       0.72
```

I want to plot all the matching points of the two dataframes on a chart like the first point would correspond to `2016-03-03, T.TO (0.1, 0.01)`. Another point would correspond to `2016-03-03, AS.TO (0.02, 0.32)` and so on giving me a large number of points. I will then use these to find a line of best fit.

I know how to find the best fit line but I am having difficulty plotting these points directly. I tried using nested for loops and dictionaries but I was wondering if there is a more straightforward approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot these points, you can `stack`:

```
plt.scatter(df1.set_index('Date').stack(), df2.set_index('Date').stack())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Ray234 that means `Date` is your index, then just forget `.set_index('Date')` altogether.

Comment: This will work if both my dataframes are the same size. However, I am pulling the data from online and some data may be missing. Is there a way to match data only for dates that are present in both the dataframes?

Comment: Yes, you can do a merge: `new_df = pd.merge(df1.stack(), df2.stack(), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')` and scatter the two columns of `new_df`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to drop out all the data that is not common between the two dataframes then this should work.

```
In [71]: df = pd.read_clipboard()

In [72]: df
Out[72]:
         Date  T.TO  AS.TO  NTR.TO   ...  R.TO
0  2016-03-03  0.10   0.02    0.04  0.02   NaN
1  2016-03-04  0.09   0.01    0.02  0.02   NaN
2  2016-03-05  0.10   0.02    0.04  0.02   NaN
3         ...   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN
4  2019-03-03  0.09   0.01    0.02  0.02   NaN

In [73]: df2 = pd.read_clipboard()

In [74]: df2
Out[74]:
         Date  T.TO  AS.TO  NTR.TO   ...  R.TO
0  2016-03-03  0.01   0.32    0.04  0.02   NaN
1  2016-03-04  0.81   0.21    0.02  0.02   NaN
2  2016-03-05  0.01   0.12    0.04  0.02   NaN
3         ...   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN
4  2019-03-03  0.89   0.11    0.12  0.72   NaN
```

Then `df3` can only have values that match the two datasets

```
In [75]: df3 = df[df==df2]

In [76]: df3
Out[76]:
         Date  T.TO  AS.TO  NTR.TO   ...  R.TO
0  2016-03-03   NaN    NaN    0.04  0.02   NaN
1  2016-03-04   NaN    NaN    0.02  0.02   NaN
2  2016-03-05   NaN    NaN    0.04  0.02   NaN
3         ...   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN
4  2019-03-03   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN
```

From there plotting is a simple matter.

Comment: This matches the *values* of the datasets, not the schema.